# Table with two foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm receiving ERROR 1064 (42000) when I'm trying to make a table that contains 2 foreign keys. It says that my syntax is wrong but I can't find anything wrong.
I'm using MySQL version 8.0

I tried with only one constraint / without the second one and it works. But with both of them I'm getting an error.

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Comment (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  content VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  date_posted DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  post_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Comment`
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES User (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

This does not:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Comment (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  content VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  date_posted DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  post_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Comment`
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES User (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Post_Comment`
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
    REFERENCES Post (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: Whats the complete error message?

Comment: In  `CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Comment`
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES User (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION),` is that last parenthesis in your actual code?

Comment: like @forpas saids one of the correct syntax is [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qMxfvP2kp8kK3tT3hAHkWq/0)

Comment: You are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I had one parenthesis extra.
Thank you guys.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Comment (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  content VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  date_posted DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  post_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Comment`
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES User (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Post_Comment`
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
    REFERENCES Post (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```